# handling different type of users with parse.com API in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am new in android. I am developing android app and using http://parse.com API. I want to implement two types of user **Student** and **Company**. Basic signup form has the same fields. Later, I want to add additional information related to the user and specific for each type. Now, problem how to save user information for different type of users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a column of userType in parse user table to differentiate user category.

And save user type during sign up and it's information.

I am also using this method because my application also has three end user.
This is working properly for me.
Hope this may helpful for you.

Comment: but what i need to do if i want to add additional attributes for each type of user. For example, **company_website** attribute, which is specific to **Company** user?

Comment: Then you should make a pointer object in parse user table and make user specific table for each type of user to handle user specific data.